# How best can I query Datomic for a n-degrees subgraph?

Tags: datomic

The Datomic documentation shows how to choose some attributes recursively:
`[:person/firstName :person/lastName {:person/friends 6}]`

But I want to pull all the attributes (I don't know them at query time).

`[* {:person/friends 6}]` does not recur... Is there a wildcard that excludes the relation I want to recur on? Is there a way to do recursive specification on a pull AND use wildcard?

Or is there a better way to construct this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timothy,

You should be able to use `["*" {:person/friends 6}]` for the behavior you're looking for.

Using the example from the [Day of Datomic pull_recursion.clj](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/tutorial/pull_recursion.clj):

```
(d/pull (d/db conn) '[:person/name {:person/friend 2}] anne-id)
;; {:person/name "anne", :person/friend [{:person/name "bob", :person/friend [{:person/name "anne"} {:person/name "lucille"}]} {:person/name "james", :person/friend [{:person/name "anne"} {:person/name "lucille"}]}]}

(d/pull (d/db conn) '["*" {:person/friend 2}] anne-id)
;; {":db/id" 17592186045418, ":person/name" "anne", ":person/friend" [{":db/id" 17592186045419} {":db/id" 17592186045420}], :person/friend [{":db/id" 17592186045419, ":person/name" "bob", ":person/friend" [{":db/id" 17592186045418} {":db/id" 17592186045421}], :person/friend [{":db/id" 17592186045418, ":person/name" "anne", ":person/friend" [{":db/id" 17592186045419} {":db/id" 17592186045420}], :person/friend [{":db/id" 17592186045419} {":db/id" 17592186045420}]} {":db/id" 17592186045421, ":person/name" "lucille", ":person/friend" [{":db/id" 17592186045419}], :person/friend [{":db/id" 17592186045419}]}]} {":db/id" 17592186045420, ":person/name" "james", ":person/friend" [{":db/id" 17592186045418} {":db/id" 17592186045421}], :person/friend [{":db/id" 17592186045418, ":person/name" "anne", ":person/friend" [{":db/id" 17592186045419} {":db/id" 17592186045420}], :person/friend [{":db/id" 17592186045419} {":db/id" 17592186045420}]} {":db/id" 17592186045421, ":person/name" "lucille", ":person/friend" [{":db/id" 17592186045419}], :person/friend [{":db/id" 17592186045419}]}]}]}
```

Marshall

Comment: After upgrading to the latest Datomic version, it works as advertised :) thanks.